# Filtering and sorting a class List based on another list in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, filter

I have a `main_lst` which contains 5 `Person` objects:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, col_name, num):
        self.col_name = col_name
        self.num = num

main_lst = []
p1 = Person("A", 5)
p2 = Person("B", 1)
p3 = Person("C", 4)
p4 = Person("D", 3)
p5 = Person("E", 2)

main_lst.append(p1)
main_lst.append(p2)
main_lst.append(p3)
main_lst.append(p4)
main_lst.append(p5)
```

I have another list just contains the `str` type `to_be_dropped_lst = ["B", "C"]`. I am trying to first exclude the `Person` objects of `main_lst` if col_name is in `to_be_dropped_lst`. Then, I want to get the remaining `col_name` in a sorted order expected below:

```
["E", "D", "A"]
```

Is there an efficient way to get this output for given two inputs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Define a getter for your col_name

```
def get_col_name(person):
    return person.get('col_name')
```

```
for value in main_lst:
  if value.col_name in to_be_dropped_lst:
    main_lst.remove(value)

main_lst.col_name.sort(key = get_col_name ,reverse= True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a dict that lets you look up a `Person` by `col` and this gets very simple.

```
person_by_col = {p.col_name: p for p in main_list}

main_list = [person_by_col[col] for col in ["E", "D", "A"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a comprehension and `attrgetter` as sorted key:

```
import operator

class Person:
    def __init__(self, col_name, num):
        self.col_name = col_name
        self.num = num

    def __repr__(self):
        "For demonstration purpose."
        return f"Person('{self.col_name}', {self.num})"
```

```
>>> sorted([p for p in main_lst if p.col_name not in to_be_dropped_lst],
           key=operator.attrgetter('num'))

[Person('E', 2), Person('D', 3), Person('A', 5)]
```